# How to correct code so that it runs or inserts formula in column to left of Range for cells that = "Metered"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where column C has a formula that looks up value if column D = "Metered".
Users, who are mostly farm workers, have the ability to overwrite it (or possibly delete it using the Make Correction button).  Unless column D = "Metered", I don't care if column C is overwritten because data validation makes sure entry is OK.  Users are supposed to Tab past column C unless load is "Metered". As a failsafe, I duplicated the "Metered" lookup formula elsewhere and the results are in column S. I don't get any errors on code below, but it doesn't do anything -- previous versions would do things but not the right things. Clearly, I cannot solve this on my own and very much appreciate any help you can provide.  I want to run the failsafe once a day when the workbook is opened (running on laptops and speed is important).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("02:57:00"), "SaveBeforeDailyRestart"
    Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection = xlToRight
    Call MeteredLookupRefreshFormula
    
End Sub

Sub MeteredLookupRefreshFormula()
  
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="Cami8"
  
    Dim bng As Range
    Set bng = Range("D8:D10009")
    
    For Each cell In bng
        If Value = "Metered" Then
            bng.Offset(0, -1).Select
            Selection.Value = "S & ActiveCell.Row)"
      Else
    End If
    
    Next
     
    Sheet1.Protect Password:="Cami8"

End Sub
```

Comment: I would at least change to `Set bng = Sheet1.Range("D8:D10009")` and `For Each cell in bng.Cells`, replace the If statement with `If cell.Value = "Metered" Then` and the two lines in it with `cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.EntireRow.Columns("S").Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Loop Through Cells

**A Quick Fix (Slow)**

- To not be dependent on the offset you could additionally do:

  ```
  cell.EntireRow.Columns("C").Value = cell.EntireRow.Columns("S").Value
  ```

```vb
Sub MeteredLookupRefreshFormulaQuickFix()
  
    With Sheet1
        .Unprotect Password:="Cami8"
        With .Range("D8:D10009")
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In .Cells
                If StrComp(CStr(cell.Value), "Metered", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.EntireRow.Columns("S").Value
                End If
            Next cell
        End With
        .Protect Password:="Cami8"
    End With

End Sub
```

### An Improvement (Fast)

- If you have many cells containing formulas evaluating to an empty string `=""` at the bottom of column `D`, replace `xlFormulas` with `xlValues` for these cells not to be processed and speed up even more.

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Refreshes...
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Calls:        RefColumn,GetRange.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub MeteredLookupRefreshFormula()
  
    Const cfcAddress As String = "D8"
    Const dCol As String = "C"
    Const sCol As String = "S"
    Const Criteria As String = "Metered"
    Const pw As String = "Cami8"
    
    Sheet1.Unprotect Password:=pw
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = RefColumn(Sheet1.Range(cfcAddress))
    If crg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data

    Dim cData As Variant: cData = GetRange(crg)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = crg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = GetRange(drg)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = GetRange(crg.EntireRow.Columns(sCol))
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(cData, 1)
        If StrComp(CStr(cData(r, 1)), Criteria, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            dData(r, 1) = sData(r, 1)
        End If
    Next r
    
    drg.Value = dData

    Sheet1.Protect Password:=pw

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range ('crg') whose first
'               cell is defined by the first cell of the range ('FirstCell')
'               and whose last cell is the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: WOW!!!, VBasic2008.  THANK YOU!  Smooth as silk now

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the contents of your FOR loop is all screwed up.  This is untested but change this ...

```
For Each cell In bng
    If Value = "Metered" Then
        bng.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Selection.Value = "S & ActiveCell.Row)"
  Else
End If

Next
```

... to this ...

```
For Each cell In bng
    If cell.Value = "Metered" Then
        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = cell.Worksheet.Range("S" & cell.Row).Value
    End If
Next
```

... and it should help.